# Why is the base manifold of a Lie groupoid required to be second-countable?

Tags: lie-groupoids

I wonder why one requires that the base manifold of a Lie groupoid is second-countable?

Comment: Isn't second-countability in the definition of manifold? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold#Definition

Comment: Usually manifolds *tout court* are required to be second countable. 

Comment: Sorry, I should state this question more carefully. Of course, Zev Chonoles and Mariano Suarez-Alvarez are right: the usual definition of a manifold requires second-countability and Hausdorff and locally euclidean. My question should merely be: At which point in the theory of Lie groupoids does one really need that the base manifold is second-countable?

When constructing a Lie groupoid from a foliation one actually has to be a bit careful at this point. If one takes uncountably many charts the base manifold of the Lie groupoid won't be second-countable. 

Comment: 
Another motivation for this question is: If one allows the manifold for the arrows to be non-Hausdorff (for good reasons), why not allow the base manifold to be non-second-countable?

Comment: @Dave Lewis: Can I request that you edit your question to include your comments above?  (Mark the edit as an edit, so that @Zev and @Mariano 's comments still make sense.)  It sounds like you have a more specific direction that you're thinking about, and in any case clearly recognize that "When constructing a Lie groupoid from a foliation one actually has to be a bit careful at this point", for example.  I do not know of a good reason to have questions on MO that are only one sentence long, and there are many good reasons for including a few paragraphs.

Comment: @Zev, Mariano, and Dave: If you require manifolds to be second countable, then a disjoint union of manifolds is not always a manifold.  Replacing second countability by paracompactness allows you to keep all good properties of second countable manifolds and makes the category of manifolds closed under coproducts, which seems like a good property to have.

Comment: +1 Dmitri. Or further, ask that there exists at least atlas which has a partition of unity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer #1:**
There is *no real reason* for imposing that the base manifold of a groupoid be second countable.

**Answer #2:**
You lose some desirable properties if you don't impose second countability:
For example, without it, 
the homotopy type of the geometric realisation of the nerve
will no longer be an invariant of the Morita equivalence class of the groupoid.

Comment: Re Answer #2: Weird!  I would have expected that the homotopy type of the nerve was a well-defined invariant for any topological groupoid, and that the construction should factor through forgetting from Manifolds to Homotopy Types.  Could you either explain more, or include a reference?

Comment: @Theo: I take my favourite non-second countable manifold: the long line $L$, and I look at the cover consisting of all of its bounded connected open subsets. The corresponding Cech groupoid is Morita equivalent to $L$. There is an obvious projection from the geometric realization of the Cech groupoid back to $L$.
But there is no section of that map: that's because the cover does not admit partitions of unity. More generally, you can show that the projection does not admit a homotopy inverse.

Comment: Ah, Andre - that is why you redefine Morita equivalence not to use 'local sections', but 'local sections wrt a numerable cover'. This class of weak equivalences of topological/Lie groupoids (take your pick) is closer to what people think of when they restrict to paracompact spaces.